# ¿Cómo instalar paquetes npm fuera de la consola npm?

Tags: nodejs, npm

Por motivos de seguridad del cliente donde laboro, no se me es permitido descargar paquetes `npm`, al intentarlo se queda cargando y no descarga el paquete requerido:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g stylus
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "stylus"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 199.27.76.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

¿Hay alguna manera de descargar los ficheros y colocarlo en la carpeta `node_modules`?, pienso que así funcionaría, o ¿de qué otra manera se pueden descargar los paquetes fuera de la consola de `npm`?

Comment: Esta no es la respuesta a tu pregunta ya que tienes que usar la consola  para lograrlo pero me gustaría comentar una forma que me ha sacado de apuros unas cuantas veces y es que puedes descargar las dependencias en una estación que no tenga restricciones y copiar la carpeta `node_modules` al lugar donde estas trabajando. Ten en cuenta que lo unico que necesitas para hacer esto es un fichero `package.json` así que si te encuentras en un ambiente restringido te funciona igual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver lo que pasa es que npm no esta configurado para las particularidades de la red de tu cliente. Puedes probar a resolverlo usando la respuesta aceptada de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac) para configurarle a npm el proxy de la red de tu cliente. Puede ser que esto no resuelva tu problema pues en algunos casos el proxy usa un esquema de autentificacion (NTLM) no soportado por npm. En ese caso puedes probar a resolver siguiendo las recomendaciones en este [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2119) de npm. Al final siempre puedes usar la variante de instalar todas las dependencias en otra máquina (en tu casa o lugar de trabajo) y luego copiar la carpeta `node_modules` (a lo mejor comprimida) hacia la máquina en la instalación del cliente. Aunque esto ultimo puede ser problemático pues a lo mejor alguna dependencia en el árbol de dependencias es un [modulo nativo de nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) y puede no funcionar bien en la otra máquina por diferencias de arquitectura o version.

No te recomiendo comprimir cada dependencia y modificar el fichero `package.json` porque esto a la larga hace el mantenimiento de la aplicación muy difícil y limita a `npm` de gestionar cuales versiones de la dependencia son soportadas por la aplicación y como actualizar las dependencias. Tampoco te recomiendo instalar dependencias de tu aplicacion de forma global como recomieda originalmente @rnd pues multiples aplicaciones en una misma maquina pueden depender de diferentes versiones de una dependencia y al hacer esto estas creando un potencial problema. Solo instala globalmente los modulos que son pensados para usar como comandos generales (como bower, gulp, yeoman, etc.).

Comment: Gracias!, esto resolvio mi problema, tocaba establecer el proxy al npm ```npm config set proxy http://1.2.3.4:8181/proxy.pac```

Comment: Por cierto yo nunca recomende instalar las dependencias globalmente, el OP ya las estaba instalando globalmente y solamente use el mismo modificador que el usaba.

Answer (score 4):

Segun la [documentacion](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) de npm install puedes utilizar la notacion

```
npm install ./paquete.tar
```

Lo que yo haría es:

Esto lo haces en la pc de tu casa, que tiene internet:

1. Clonas el repositorio: ej: `git clone https://github.com/stylus/stylus`
2. Creas un `stylus.tar` de la carpeta clonada. (puedes utilizar http://www.7-zip.org/)
3. Te auto envías el `stylus.tar` por email o lo copias en un pen drive.

Esto luego en la pc del trabajo:

1. Copias el `stylus.tar` en tu disco.
2. Ejecutas `npm install ./stylus.tar -g`

## Actualización:

Si el paquete tiene dependencias, el proceso es bastante mas complicado:

Deberías descargar también las dependencias y luego editar `package.json` antes de hacer el `.tar`.

Ejemplo de package.json para stylus

```
"dependencies": {
    "css-parse": "file:./cssparse.tar",
    "mkdirp": "file:./mkdirp.tar",
    "debug": "file:./debug.tar",
    "sax": "file:./sax.tar",
    "glob": "file:./glob.tar",
    "source-map": "file:./sourcemap.tar"
}
```

Este proceso puede crecer mucho, ya que debes repetir con los pasos para cada paquete.

Como dices, sera mas fácil si logras que te abren el firewall, o en todo caso puedes utilizar la internet de tu celular, o un acceso alternativo.

Comment: Hola Gracias, mi estación de trabajo tiene conexión a Internet, por suerte si puedo ingresar a GitHub sin problemas, así que me fui a descargar el fuente, pero me percate de algo, npm al hacer la instalación del `.tar` busca el archivo `package.json` y empieza a instalar las dependencias, y o problema, me tocaría hacer lo mismo que hice con stylus para las dependencias. Ni modo, me toco mirar como pido que habiliten `npm` en la red del cliente.